# Moved Visual Studio Project - Directory Not Found Exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have recently copied an entire Visual Studio project (folder containing all files and subfolders) from one machine to another.

I've then opened the project .sln file, and hit debug. The first error that i get it that it can't find Form1 (the very first Windows Form in my project). It gives me the option to select the file manually, but if i navigate to the Form1 file it tells me that the:

```
Source file is different from when the module was built. Would you like the debugger to use it anyway?
```

If i do this, the next thing i get is a DirectoryNotFoundException whereby it's looking at this file path:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'O:\TestDaws\CSDB'.
```

Now this file path did exist where i was running this program from previously (at work). Now i'm trying to run it from home, it does not. But i cannot find ANYWHERE that refers to the O: drive in my code. Tried searching and it finds nothing.

The only answers i can find seem related to Source Control. And i have no source control. Also seen people recommending deleting the .suo file. I'e tried that and that also has no affect.

The file path it's looking for must be in some meta data or settings file somewhere that Visual Studio creates, and i can't find. Any ideas please?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you rebuilt the project. Did you clean and rebuild the entire solution on the new machine? Most likely the paths are in the output files.

Comment: Check your project and solution files for absolute paths

Comment: Yep, now i feel stupid. Indeed i had not rebuilt the project on the new machine. School-boy error. Thank you though.